# How to configure Look up filter

Tags: lookup-filter

I,ve one Parent object '**Patient**'  and Child Object '**Patient Services'** and another Parent object '**Job**'.

On **Patient Services** Object one Look up field Named **Patient** related to **Patient object** & another lookup field Named **job** related to **job** object.
The Location Field  on both object **Patient and Job**.

When adding a Patient Service from the Patient object; then the Job field lookup should filter based on the Location of the Patient.

[image: User-added image]

When I click on Job lookup field icon, it allow to show me only record that has location field is equal to  location field of **Patient** record , **Patient 000972** in above image.

How to configure in look filter Please help